# How to share database over network folder

Tags: database

I want to make an app for my job and for this, I need a database because my app is used by 5 persons simultaneously, I can't use a client/server architecture because it's difficult in my company to install this (big company...).
I read a lot of topics about this but no solutions.
Can anyone had an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does every person, who will be using your app, has access to Internet (or any other network, they share)? If so, what prevents you from putting database on remote server?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, yes all persons can access to internet but in this database there are "confidential" data and I can't use external server.

Comment: Then you need to use your internal network. If people don't have shared network it's impossible to share database among them.

Comment: network is shared, we have access to a network shared folder. Plan to use a file based database like mysql, paradox, interbase.

Comment: Sharing database through the shared folder is **really** bad solution and you'll have a lot of problems because of conflicts between different computers changes. You probably can find some databases, which are able to survive that, but... I would highly discourage it. If you have shared folder, you most likely can find a server (or usual computer, which always turned on) and install database in a normal way on that computer. Than you can access it over the network.

Comment: maybe I'll do that, I found a computer and use it as a server, it's the only correct solution... thanks.